# How to show a yes / no dialog from vs code extension api

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing a extension in vscode and at some point i need to ask confirmation from user for some code action.

I would like to prompt a dialog and get either yes or now, i am not able to find any method like confirm or alert in vscode api
Can you some one help

Comment: with the information messages you can add buttons that will be the result of the Thenable `showInformationMessage()`

Comment: @LexLi the link is now broken

Comment: @Ani The original documentation can be found in https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window.showInformationMessage Sample code can be found in GitHub code search (as so many extensions are hosted there).

Answer (score 18):

Seems like you're looking for `vscode.window.showInformationMessage` witch takes two parameters `message` and `...items` (for more info see [API reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api)). Can be used as in this example:

```js
vscode.window
  .showInformationMessage("Do you want to do this?", "Yes", "No")
  .then(answer => {
    if (answer === "Yes") {
      // Run function
    }
  })
```